# Oauth1 call for tradevine api using curl

Tags: php, curl, oauth

I am trying to make HTTP GET to https://api.tradevine.com/v1/SalesOrder as given in https://api.tradevine.com/Help/api-reference/get-sales-orders.html

I have already obtained Consumer Key, Consumer Secret, Access Token and Token Secret by creating a new application as given [here](https://support.tradevine.com/tradevine-help/organisation-details/api-applications/).

Now how should I make this call using curl? 
Is there a standard way to make such oauth1 calls given the access token and access token secret? (all places I found pass only one token in the curl commands as authorization header)

Comment: In PHP, one of the best HTTP clients these days is Guzzle (https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle), which provides support to do everything you need for this. That being said, the spec recommends using the `Authorization` header: http://oauth.net/core/1.0a/#auth_header

Comment: @cillosis thanks. Although the question has php in its tags, I am actually trying to do this http request using google apps script. Since I have the token and secret, I need to make the request using these two parameters in header.